# How to manage JWT token stored in cookie in incognito mode?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, jwt, incognito-mode

I recently decided to implement JWT authentication in expressjs and storing it in a cookie. Previously I had only used localstorage for storing JWT in frontend(reactjs). But now I have faced an issue with my new cookie storing approach - cookies are disabled in Incognito mode of browser and my app breaks in it. I am not a complete expert on cookies so maybe I am doing something wrong. Also the API is hosted on a different domain than the frontend(are third party cookies disabled in incognito or all of them)? So my question is how do I make it work, currently when I look in chrome dev tools, cookie is not stored apparently at all in incognito mode. Does anyone know how to overcome this problem?

Comment: "cookies are disabled in Incognito mode".. i doubt this because if this is the case, all FB, youtube and basically everything will not work in incognito. I believe there is some other problems other than browser issue

Comment: Could the API hosted on different domain url be causing this? Maybe only third party cookies are disabled in incognito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have confirmed this. Third party cookies are blocked by default by browser in incognito mode. You need to have the API on the same domain so it could work in incognito too.

Comment: If front.website.com made requests to back.website.com, using cookies, would they be first party? Or will they still be third parties if using the same domain, but on two different subdomains?

Comment: Yes, first party. The main domain needs to be the same. Then even if you use different subdomains, cookies won't be blocked by browsers as third party. I know it because I have implemented this very recently and it works.