# Passport cookies not working on Incognito mode

Tags: session, cookies

I can't find any clue about this problem, what make me wonder if I am wrong from basic knowledge.

I am building an application with mongo, nodejs (with passport), and react.

Users can log in into this application correctly in normal windows browsers.

`Session cookie` is set with passport, and the flow is working.

Problem starts, when I tried to log in through Incognito Mode from google chrome (or any other browser).

Is any problem about cookie session in Incognito Mode?
Should I use other method to go over this case?

I think it is not relevant any code of how I set cookie session, but if someone need it I will paste it.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I had the same problem... and I read this: [Third party cookies are blocked by default by browser in incognito mode. You need to have the API on the same domain so it could work in incognito too.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64182844/how-to-manage-jwt-token-stored-in-cookie-in-incognito-mode)